# Detect change in an <input> field controlled by a slider

Tags: javascript, slider, zurb-foundation

I have a form with a double-handles slider:

```
<form id="advancedSearch" action="modules/advanced_search.xq" method="post" onsubmit="advancedSearch(this);">

<div class="slider" id="slider" data-aria-valuemin="1725" data-aria-valuemax="1786" data-slider="data-slider" data-start="1725" data-end="1786" data-initial-start="1725" data-initial-end="1786">

<span id="handle1" class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle="data-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="dateFrom"/>

<span id="handle2" class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle="data-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="dateTo"/>

[...]
<input type="number" max="1786" min="1725" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom"/>
</div>
<div class="cell small-2">
<input type="number" max="1786" min="1725" id="dateTo" name="dateTo"/>
[...]
</form>
```

It all works well.
Now, I'd like to call the function advancedSearch() when changing the slider's handle, without having to hit 'submit' each time.

Adding a `oninput='advancedSearch(this.form); return false;'` to the `<input>` elements does the trick only if I change the numbers inside the `<input>` field. When using the sliders, although `document.getElementById('dateFrom').value` does get changed, does not trigger the function. `onchange` also doesn't work. How can I call the function when changing the number by using the slider itself, other than changing the numbers inside the `<input>` field manually?

Adding a separate function:

```
document.getElementById('dateFrom').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
var formData = document.getElementById('advancedSearch')

advancedSearch(formData)
});
```

yields the same result.

Comment: usually a slider library gives an event for changing the slider. What slider library are you using. you might be able to use 
                    document.getElementById('dateFrom').addEventListener("click", function(){
   advancedSearch(document.getElementById('advancedSearch'));
});

Comment: @PrikeshSavla I'm using Foundation. Changing your code from getElementById('dateFrom') to getElementById('handle1') actually detects the click on the handle, i.e. when the date gets changed, so it seems to work that way. Two questions though: how can I detect also the handle1 and the manual date input? Am I going to replicate the code for those inputs too? And more importantly, is this mobile/tablet friendly?

Comment: Is this the one?  If so then it provides js events to trigger value changes. you can follow the link and at the bottom you find the event "changed.zf.slider" -  https://get.foundation/sites/docs/slider.html#js-events

Comment: OK, I solved the issue of selecting both handles by using document.querySelector('#slider').

Comment: I'd suggest using the class in the querySelector to get all the handles in one event function If there are more sliders in the view

Comment: If everything works. I'd suggest posting your answer down and completing the question.

Comment: OK, you're right, I should use Foundation's own trigger. There's an issue though: the advanced search function now gets triggered when loading/reloading the html page where the form is, i.e. the table shows up (as it should) for a moment, and then the search is triggered with default values. Any idea why is that? That's what I'm using:
$("#slider").on('change changed.zf.slider', function(){ {
                            var formData = document.getElementById('advancedSearch')

                            advancedSearch(formData);
                            }});

Comment: try switching to "moved.zf.slider"

Comment: No, same thing. I'm troubleshooting it and will post an update here if I find what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Prikesh Savla for pointing me towards the `changed.zf.slider` event. Unfortunately when implementing that with:

```
$("#slider").on('change changed.zf.slider', function(){ { var formData = document.getElementById('advancedSearch') advancedSearch(formData); }});
```

the page calls the function when loading it (either refreshing or landing there). After some troubleshooting I haven't been able to find the reason for that. In the end I'm adding this code:

```
document.querySelector('.slider').addEventListener("click", function () {
            advancedSearch(document.getElementById('advancedSearch'));
        });
        document.getElementById('dateFrom').addEventListener("input", function () {
            advancedSearch(document.getElementById('advancedSearch'));
        });
        document.getElementById('dateTo').addEventListener("input", function () {
            advancedSearch(document.getElementById('advancedSearch'));
        });
```

which does what I want, although I appreciate that it's not the most elegant solution.

Comment: You probably forgot to put this in the jQuery.ready part which waits until the document is ready. Also on('input change') does work too.